# Emacs git plugin - egg

Tags: git, emacs, emacs-egg

I have emacs **egg** plugin version 1.0.0 with me. I have git **1.7.4** version installed. I would like know how to push/pull changes to/from the repository. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.0.0 means you have [byplayer's egg](https://github.com/byplayer/egg) version, not the original one [from bogolisk](https://github.com/bogolisk/egg).

However, the latter (and older) [egg wiki page](https://github.com/bogolisk/egg/wiki) mentions:

- <kbd>U</kbd> `egg-log-buffer-push-to-remote`: remote upload: update the tracking target of ref under the cursor. If the ref under the cursor wasn’t a remote tracking branch, the command will prompt for remote and target names.
- <kbd>d</kbd> `egg-log-buffer-fetch-remote`: remote download: download and update the ref under the cursor(`git fetch`)

Those functions are accessible through:

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>: `egg-log` shows HEAD’s history.

With a prefix (<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>), show history of all refs (`git log`).

---

Make sure, though, that your [`git.exe` is in your Emacs path (`ExecPath`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521985/egg-git-interface-for-emacs-commit-message-empty/2537003#2537003), not just your `PATH`.

---

To highlight what the comments are mentioning:

- A pull is a fetch + a merge (usually merging the `HEAD` of a *remote* branch -- i.e. a branch fetched in the 'remotes' namespace -- to the `HEAD` of the current local branch).
  So:

  - You need to browse all refs
  - Type 'd' on a remote branch
  - Then type 'm' on that same (now updated by the fetch) remote branch, in order to merge it with the the current branch.

The last two operations are what constitutes a pull: fetch + merge.

Comment: @VonC - Thanks, upload works fine with U. But 'd' does not appear to be working. In egg-log origin/master disappears and the entry becomes **`* -  master ba456ebb Committing README file`**. When I inspect what is happening with 'magit' plugin new changes in the repository(pushed from somewhere else) come as **unpulled commmits**

Comment: @arun: don't forget that d is a '`git fetch`', meaning it won't change any of your file, because it won't *pull* any of the remote files (i.e. it will fetch but not merge said files): hence the "unpulled commits" status. You still need to merge an unpulled commit to HEAD ("m") if you want to actually pull it.

Comment: when I give 'm' on local-branch (master) I get a confirmation **merge master to HEAD? (y or n)**. When I give 'y' it says **GIT-MERGE> Already up-to-date.**. But I still don't have an updated codebase.

Comment: @amur: that seems normal: your local branch cannot merge on itself. But you should be able, with C-u l) to browse logs for *all* branches, including *remote* branches: those are the ones updated by the 'd' fetch; and those are the commits you can merge to `HEAD` (completing the second step of a pull, which is fetch + merge).

Comment: @arun: excellent! I have included those comment findings in the answer for more visibility.